# Why isn't sort -u or uniq removing duplicates in concatenated text files?

Tags: sorting, text, duplicates, text-processing, uniq

I am trying to write a bash script to take three user dictionaries from various places across my boxen, and combine them, remove duplicates and then write them back to their respective areas.

However, when I `cat` the files, and either perform a `sort -u` or a `uniq`, the duplicate lines remain:

```
Alastair
Alastair
Albanese
Albanese
Alberts
Alberts
Alec
Alec
Alex
Alex
```

I narrowed it down to one of the files, which comes from Microsoft Outlook/Windows and is called CUSTOM.DIC. By examining it with `file -i` I found that it was a UTF-16le file (and was printing oriental characters when concatenated with UTF-8 files directly), so I ran the command

```
iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 CUSTOM.DIC -o CUSTOMUTF8.DIC
```

Yet, when I concatenate that file with my other UTF-8 files, it produces duplicates that cannot be removed using `sort -u` or `uniq`.

I have found that for large files, `file -i` only guesses the file format from the first (many) thousand lines, so I ran the commands

```
file_to_check="CUSTOMUTF8.DIC"
bytes_to_scan=$(wc -c < $file_to_check)
file -b --mime-encoding -P bytes=$bytes_to_scan $file_to_check
```

with the output:

[image: Output code of file type check]

so the conversion has happened, the output file `combined.txt` is UTF-8 also, so why can't I remove the duplicate lines?

[image: combined output file showing duplicates]

I have also checked to see if there are any trailing spaces in the combined file.

This feels like a problem that many people would have seen before, but I can't find the answer (or I've created the wrong search string, of course)...

Comment: Given I see two of each, offhand I'd guess one has `\n` linefeeds and the other has `\r\n` linefeeds.  Do a hex dump of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @[Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle) - I knew it would be something simple!

Indeed, using `hexdump -c combined2.txt` I saw that some lines ended with a `\n` and some with `\r\n`.

So I downloaded `dos2unix` and ran

```
dos2unix combined2.txt
sort -u combine2.txt > combined3.txt
```

and it's all good!

Thanks again, Andrew!